# How do you solve the eigenproblem for the adiabatic Grover algorithm?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, hamiltonian, quantum-computer

The [adiabatic](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0107015) version of Grover's algorithm relies on a straightforward solution of the Schrodinger equation when the Hamiltonian is allowed to linearly vary from its initial state to its final state. The solution is given in the paper (and [other](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Evazirani/pubs/adiabatic.pdf) [references](https://link.aps.org/accepted/10.1103/RevModPhys.90.015002)) directly *without actually solving the problem*. I suppose the result is 'obvious' to physicists, but I have an engineering background; how do I actually solve Equation 2 in the first link by using Equation 10? (The Schrodinger equation with a linearly interpolated Hamiltonian).

I crossposted on Quantum Computing StackExchange and am posting here for greater visibility.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Does it actually have anything to do with the specific form of $H(t)$ or are you asking how to solve an eigenvalue problem? Or rather, _why_ we want to solve this particular eigenvalue problem?

Comment: @noah I am asking a bit of everything, I guess. Specifically, there's a sentence in the first linked paper that says 'Using Eq. (10) or (11), we can solve the eigenproblem
(2) and evaluate (3) and (4)'. (Equation 10 is the linear interpolation of the Hamiltonian, and (2) is the Schrodinger equation). I am asking how to solve the Schrodinger equation given this specific Hamiltonian.